# python program doesnt execute all classes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created 2 classes in 2 different files. When I call these 2 classes in my main program the program only executes the first class. How do I make the module return back to main program?

file 1

```
 class a:
     do something
```

file 2

```
  class b:
      do something
```

file 3

```
import a
import b

a
print("hello")
b
```

What  happens is that on run time `a` executes but not `print` or `b`, can anyone help me understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these are classes that just run a block of code, consider using a function. File 1 and 2 would be changed to be in the format

```
def a():
    do something
def b():
    do something
```

Then file 3 will look like:

```
import a
import b
a()
print('hello')
b()
```

---

If you are insistent on using classes, you can put all of the code in the `__init__` method of the class. The `__init__` method is called whenever a new  object is instanciated... File 1 and 2 would look like this

```
class a():
    def __init__(self):
        do something

class b():
    def __init__(self):
        do something
```

File 3 would then look like:

```
import a
import b
a = a()
print('hello')
b = b()
```

Comment: Thank you very much I must have made some mistake earlier it worked now as a function